# Paypal Subscription button mobile layout not working

Tags: mobile, layout, paypal

I searched through all the "paypal" related questions and didn't find a response.

So I have a mobile website and I created a Subscription button for a service I am offering.

How do I make this link work on mobile website?

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=GFVXMNRBE98NS

on the desktop browser it works perfect but I would like to get this layout:

http://www.mobilecommercedaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/crutchfield-paypal-2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, mobile layout is not supported for **Subscription** buttons.

For now only merchants integrated with '**Buy Now**' buttons or third party shopping carts (using “**Cart** Upload”) will benefit from [Mobile PayPal Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/mobile-paypal-payments-standard/).